# Потерял пароль от админки MODX

Tags: безопасность, modx, админка

Добрый день! Я делаю сайт на MODX Revo на Localhost.
Я использую сборку Ampps.
По глупости заменил права на все папки внутри ampps на 777, а потом — на 755.
В phpmyadmin могу зайти, но на сам сайт через панель управления — не могу.
Пишет «Неправильное имя пользователя или пароль».
Пробовал следовать этой инструкции: http://wideas.ru/2015/02/reset_admin_password_mod_revo/
В базе в таблице inar_users поменял hash_class на hashing.modMD5
Удалил значение salt, сменил password на 'pass', указав при этом MD5
Не помогло. Мне кажется, что-то не так с правами доступа к файлам на локальном сервере

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в таблице inar_users ,
salt очищаем ,
password ставим 827ccb0eea8a706c4c34a16891f84e7b ,
hash_class ставим hashing.modMD5 ,
и при входе в админку пароль будет 12345

Answer (score 0):

Скачайте заново файлы установки, залейте поверх с заменой и запустите установку. Должно помочь.